# ListView disappears on rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments

Fragment **onCreateView** method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myCustomFragmentLayout, null);

        MyFragmentClass.myListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        MyFragmentClass.counter = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        return view;
}
```

Fragment **onStart** method

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Builder builder;
        try {
            builder = new Builder();

            MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask (this, builder);
            task.execute();

        } catch (MyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Async **onTaskFinished** method

```
public void onTaskFinished(BuilderResult result) {
        // check if ListAdapter instance was ever created
        if(null == MyFragmentClass.listAdapter) {
            MyFragmentClass.listAdapter = new MyListAdapter(MyApplication.getContext(), (ArrayList<ListItem>)result.getList());
            MyFragmentClass.myListView.setAdapter(MyFragmentClass.listAdapter);         
        } else {
            MyFragmentClass.listAdapter.clear();
            MyFragmentClass.listAdapter.addCalls((ArrayList<ListItem>)result.getList());
        }

        MyFragmentClass.counter.setText(String.valueOf(result.getTotalCounter()));      

        // dismiss progress dialog
        MyFragmentClass.progressDialog.dismiss();
        MyFragmentClass.progressDialog = null;
}
```

Due to `Fragment` object casting I must have static widget objects.

**PROBLEM:** `ListView` dissapears on rotation change. Do not know why `ListView` is not visible after activity is recreated.

**EDITED**

Casting and executing filter method of base fragment objects.

```
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {

        for(int i = 0; i < mTabsAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            Fragment fragment = mTabsAdapter.getItem(i);

            if(fragment instanceof BaseOmoFragment) {
                ((BaseOmoFragment) fragment).filter();
            }
        }
}
```

P.S. I should mention that I use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library.

Comment: can you please provide getView() method from your code? and if possible xml also..

Comment: Is it necessary if I say that on rotation method `getView` of adapter never executes? I think problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: *Due to fragment object casting I must have static widget objects.* - Please don't do this. How do you use this fragment?

Comment: Activity has more than one fragment. Fragments have ListView widgets. I have to perform filtering from acitivity perspective to all fragments. There is base fragment class with abstract `filter` method which all fragments implements. On filter, in Activity, I iterate through all fragments which I got from `FragmentPagerAdapter`. While iterating I get `Fragment` object so I must to cast to base fragment class to execute `filter` method. During casting all Fragments object fields values are lost. So I thought to use static class fields. It seems that I should rethink implementation.

Comment: Static fields are 1) leaking memory and 2) totally the wrong thing to do.

The reason "all Fragments object fields values are lost" is because you're calling the Fragment's `filter` method before it has reached onCreateView in its lifecycle. Casting does not in any share or form clear fields - you're either too early or too late.

Comment: @Delyan you was right. The problem is not due to casting. It is due to actionsherlockbar sample implementation. Reimplemented without static widget fields. Problem is solved.